# What type of Ferrari's came with wire wheels?

Tags: wheels, ferrari

I always thought wire wheels was a British thing but recently I saw a very neat looking Classic Ferrari with wire wheels. Was this odd for an Italian car? Did they come stock with these or was it just an after market fitting some owners did?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Ferrari and Borrani

According to [the Borrani Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borrani):

> Between 1946 and 1966, all Ferrari cars were equipped with Borrani wheels as original equipment.

Looking for Ferrari cars built during these years should be a good starting point to answer your question. Moreover, Borrani also supplied wire wheels to Lamborghini, Maserati and Alfa Rome, hence hinting at the fact that wire wheels were indeed a common feature of Italian cars.

#### Which Ferrari's Have Wire Wheels?

An example of Ferrari coming with wire wheels is the [Ferrari 250 GTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrari_250_GTO) which came with Borrani wire wheels OEM:

[image: FErrari 250 GTO] 
*<sup>Image courtesy of Wikipedia</sup>*

Comment: Are you saying this was the _only_ Ferrari with wire wheels or just one example that definitely had wire wheels?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Just one example.

Comment: Is there a difference between Italian wire wheels and the British counterparts or is this a relatively homogeneous product.