# Is RAV4 SE higher trim than RAV4 XLE?

Tags: toyota, rav4, vehicle-identification

I read a lot of articles online, but still don't understand.  Is RAV4 SE higher trim than RAV4 XLE ? I asked two different dealers and got two different answers .

I understand SE is the sport version .

**So which one is higher level?**

Comment: I do not think this question should be closed.  The OP was not asking for price shopping assistance.  They were asking for a comparison of trim levels between models and what one was of a higher level of trim package.  Please do NOT close.

Comment: Is this question related ".. to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and their accessories", even remotely?  Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing at all to do with either Maintenance or Repair.  It has everything to do with understanding a manufacturers marketing program involving trim levels.

Comment: @zipit I don't see how it's any different than http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/28859/what-type-of-ferraris-came-with-wire-wheels

Comment: @Ben right you are.  I didn't make the rules or establish the goals here.  But you are exactly right, we all should have voted to close that one too.   Perhaps it's time to challenge the written guidelines and expand the goals of this forum (via meta)?

Comment: @Ben, check out [this](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/what-are-the-specific-guidelines-in-this-forum-for-automotive-marketing-sales)

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question.  **It's on-topic for the site.**

Comment: I think that "and their accessories" gives this question merit even if you do feel that the once sentence on the help page is the only written in stone rule.  You need to be able to identify the trim level on a car you're going to work on so you know what the differences are.

Comment: I don't really like this question, but I think it is on topic so I'm adding my vote.

Answer (score 5):

If you go to Toyota's website, http://www.toyota.com/configurator/#!/build/step/model/year/2016/series/rav4. There is an option to compare all available trim levels.

If you're not interested in the larger 18" wheels and certain sport features than the comparison should be between the Limited and XLE editions. The Limited edition comes with more standard features.

If you are comparing just the SE and XLE editions than the SE comes with more standard features.

Comment: Ben, thank you . So which one is a higher level . It is confusing

Comment: @Emily the highest trim level would be the Limited.